Why doesn’t the ASGI specification allow handshake rejection with custom reason?
A client initially opens a connection to an ASGI compliant server. The server forwards a Connect event [asgi-spec] to the application. This event must be responded to with either an Accept event [asgi-spec] or a Close event. [asgi-spec] The server must send this event during the handshake phase of the WebSocket and not complete the handshake until it gets a reply.
If the application responds with a Close event, the server must close the connection with a HTTP 403 status code and not complete the WebSocket handshake.

Why simply 403? Not even a reason key is allowed to be part of the event responded. Just 403. You would expect that it is during handshake that Authentication would be done hence a possible 401.
The WebSocket Protocol specification allows any HTTP status code besides 101.

Any status code other than 101 indicates that the WebSocket handshake has not completed and that the semantics of HTTP still apply.

What is the rationale behind ASGI’s specification?

I think the ASGI specification on this matter limits server developers and hence Python applications that use ASGI compliant servers.

As explained in ASGI Extensions spec (which allows using other HTTP status code on rejection), the rationale behind this decision seems to be for the sake of simplicity in most practical cases:

The core ASGI specification does not allow for any control over the
denial response, instead specifying that the HTTP status code 403
should be returned, whereas this extension allows an ASGI framework to
control the denial response. Rather than being a core part of ASGI,
this is an extension for what is considered a niche feature as most
clients do not utilise the denial response.

You may find more details regarding this matter in these comments:

https://github.com/django/asgiref/pull/42#issuecomment-390104476
https://github.com/django/asgiref/pull/42#issuecomment-390307934

And especially this one

https://github.com/django/asgiref/pull/42#issuecomment-390378550


Hmm, right, that situation makes sense, though it's still a bit
strange. The question I'm asking is if it's worth asking servers to
implement a LOT more complexity (in Daphne's case, this is going to
require a lot of new code as the HTTP and WebSocket paths are very
separate) for a very edge use-case.
ASGI already deliberately does not cover some of the more obscure
parts of the HTTP spec - like sending headers mid-stream between
chunks - because it's not worth supporting a 1% feature to make code
more complex. Do you think this is? Would having it not be there be a
make-or-break for you to help adopt it? Once something is in a spec it
is near-impossible to remove.
Also, as for close codes, I agree mixing the namespace would be
confusing. Could add a separate http_status option to the close
instead to make it cleaner.


Master piece. I couldn’t get this far with all my searching but for posterity, this will serve as a good head start for future server developers. +1.

The decision to restrict handshake responses was driven mostly by a desire for simplicity and consistency. By specifying a single status code (403), ASGI simplifies the server's implementation and ensures consistent behavior. Developers can thus rely on a predictable response for handshake rejections, making debugging and troubleshooting "more straightforward" (read as air-quotes, your opinion may vary).
The WebSocket Protocol specification does allow for any HTTP status code besides 101 to indicate that the handshake has not completed. WSGI avoids this by not implementing a standard for WebSocket handling and letting other components handle protocol-specific details. ASGI brings with it added complexity. ASGI is broader in scope and choose to use 403. This is arguably more Pythonic as it enforces the pep 20 mentality with "...only one obvious way to do it".
